# Linking to an external website using frames

Tags: html, hyperlink, frame

I have a question I'm hoping someone can help me out with.

We are creating a website which is supposed to link to an external site, which is using frames. Problem is we have to link to a sub page and keep the frames intact.

Here is the link

http://www.bridge.dk/4450/

If I try to link to the sub page which is located here

http://www.bridge.dk/4450/Klub13/KlubTurn.html

I lose the top frame, which holds the menu making it impossible to navigate.

Is there a way to link to the sub page, but keeping the top frame?

Comment: How are you linking to the sub page? from within the page that is in the frame?

Comment: No its an external link from our own site (which is not using frames).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they don't have a frame page setup with that information then you can't create it externally. What you could do is create a frame page yourself and have the header link to their header and the body to that page.

So your page would look like this:

```
<FRAMESET FRAMEBORDER="0" BORDER="0" FRAMESPACING="0" ROWS="88,*" COLS="100%"> 

<FRAME SRC="http://www.bridge.dk/4450/HovedTop.html" NAME="TopRamme" SCROLLING="no" MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0" NORESIZE> 

<FRAME SRC="http://www.bridge.dk/4450/Klub13/KlubTurn.html" NAME="HovedRamme" SCROLLING="auto" MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0"> 

</FRAMESET>
```